# htaccess redirect to a folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wasn't sure what the title should be but its s simple concept but I'm useless with .htaccess rewrites.

I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

which will happily send all requests to my index and I can do what I want.

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^events/([a-zA-Z0-9-./]+)/?$ index.php?page=events/index&id=$1
```

For more intermit stuff..

But I want to say

**If the url is "/mycms/..." Send use to %{HTTP_HOST}/cms and stay there...**

Can anyone help? my 'catch all' rule keeps fecking it up.

---

***Edit*** I Got this to work wonderful

```
RewriteRule ^mycms([a-zA-Z0-9-./]+)?$ /cms$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Now I write *http://localhost/mycms* and will head off to *http://localhost/cms*

I still want to mask the '/cms/' folder though... o_O

Comment: I have absolutely no concept of what you mean by 'mask', you are masking it because you are using mycms...

Comment: I do not want the user to see the true path of the CMS. Therefore I can bury it within a nest of folders. I would like the user to see the simple url seen here. Ergo... Masked. A Masked URL.

Comment: Are you saying that now, when you go to `http://localhost/mycms`, you get redirected in the browser to `http://localhost/cms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place a rewrite before your catch all and use the L flag to prevent it being rewritten again, something like this should suffice.

```
RewriteRule ^events/([a-zA-Z0-9-./]+)/?$ index.php?page=events/index&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Ye I tried that but it never seemed to work for me. As if the [L] flag wasn't working.

Comment: Exactly what URI do you wish the request to be made to (i.e. what will be in the address bar) and what page do you wish to be shown?

Comment: I would like to `http://example.com/mycms` to `http://example.com/cms`  but masked. Reason is, the current way the company has of rebranding the CMS is literally changing folder names...